# Remove characters before and including a specific symbol

Tags: php, string

I have a string `<?php $linktitle = get_the_title();?>` that stores the title of the post. The string has a title like this:

> If Your Wi-Fi Is Terrible, Check Your Router – The New York Times

How can I remove everything before and including the `–`? I'm using: `<?php echo strstr($linktitle, '&#8211;'); ?>` and it outputs:

> – The New York Times

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309420/3367144)

Comment: `array_pop(explode(' - ', $linktitle))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `preg_replace`:

```
preg_replace("/.+?( –)/", '', $linktitle)
```

If you want to remove the whitespace after the `-` too:

```
preg_replace("/.+?( –)\s*/", '', $linktitle)
```

This uses regular expression to match a pattern defined by any character except newline 1 or more times (`.+`), until it meets (`?`) a space followed by a dash (`( –)`), then a whitespace (`\s`) 0 or more times (`*`). Preg_replace then replaces the matched pattern with an empty string.

Comment: `$links = preg_replace("/.+?( &#8211;)/", '', $linktitle);` Thanks!

Comment: Using a regexp for that is a little bit overkill. I'd advise using Vishnu's answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you need output like

> – The New York Times

from

> If Your Wi-Fi Is Terrible, Check Your Router – The New York Times

so try to use it may help you ,

```
  $linktitle = "If Your Wi-Fi Is Terrible, Check Your Router – The New York Times";

  echo substr($linktitle,strrpos($linktitle,'–'));
```

> EDIT :

If you need to remove the `"–"` too .  use this ,

```
 $linktitle         = "If Your Wi-Fi Is Terrible, Check Your Router – The New York Times";
 $specCharLen   = strlen(htmlentities("–"));
 echo substr($linktitle,strrpos($linktitle,'–')+$specCharLen);
```

Comment: Needs the dash removed as well.